# Are hot machine learning solutions -like the Show, Attend and Tell paper- instances of unsupervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning

The Show, Attend and Tell paper describes a solution to [image captioning](http://cv-tricks.com/artificial-intelligence/show-attend-tell-image-captioning-explained/).

I am wondering: **Is this novel machine learning application and instances of (semi-)supervised or unsupervised learning (in the broadest sense)? And if not, why?**

My confusion comes from the fact that for disconnect that I'm experiencing, when learning introductory machine learning concepts, where *everything is categorized as a (semi-)supervised problem, where the output is either a vector or a label or unsupervised learning problem, where clustering is performed* - and the above solution, whose output seems to be a much more complicated object, for example a word.

I guess one could encode words in vectors or labels drawn from a large pools of possible labels, but I'm very doubtful if this is actually how it is done.
The machine learning solutions from the textbooks, that I learned so far, only seem to apply for problems where the output is a number (such as predicting a the income in a country based on years of education and age) or a label (such as in the Iris dataset). But the linked problem seem of a very different category.

(I tried going over the details of the Show, Attend and Tell paper. While I do know a bit of stats, I lacked machine learning knowledge to be able to discern whether their is ultimately a supervised or unsupervised machine learning solution.)

Comment: Are all these novel machine learning applications instances of (semi-)supervised or unsupervised learning (in the broadest sense)? - no. As to why, you should ask separate questions (for example answer to image captioning is pretty complicated).

Comment: @JakubBartczuk I'm not really interested in a fully explanatory why they are not (un)supervised learning example - but rather, under what classification they would fall in that case. If that is still too large for a single answer, just pick any of the mentioned example to give an example - I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @JakubBartczuk Edited yet again, now I'm solely focussing in the Show, Attend and Tell paper

Comment: Please 1. edit the title to focus solely on this paper 2. give a full refrence to the paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This paper is very much a supervised learning problem.

> I guess one could encode words in vectors or labels drawn from a large pools of possible labels, but I'm very doubtful if this is actually how it is done.

You are right. Words are typically represented as a categorical variable. The vocabulary size for neural models is typically on the order of 10000 (as it was for this paper).